# How to split a variable that contains 32 Hex-values into 32 Bytes in C?

Tags: c, byte

I have a variable which contains 32 bytes or 28 hexadecimal Values:
The variable is defined like the following:

```
unsigned char cAll_Data[200] = {0};
```

And has got the following value inside by compiling the code:

```
3074F701CC0D90C000000A6A3030303000000000313030303030303000010484
```

Since I would like to calculate the CRC checksum of the value of this variable, the variable cAll_Data should have only 32 Bytes for each byte spot as the following:

```
30 74 F7 01 CC 0D 90 C0 00 00 0A 6A 30 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 31 30 30 
30 30 30 30 30 00 01 04 84
```

But the problem is that each one digit is considered as 1 byte which results at the end 64 Bytes.

Is there any way how to put each two digets instead of one in a variable of 32 bytes?

The code has mainly the function call and the definition of the variable, so I only need how to put these data in a 32 bytes variable.
Edit:
Since I am working with ANSI C, here is the part of the code that contains the informations abotu the variables:

```
char x_Result_B0            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B1            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B2            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B3            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B4            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B5            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B6            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B7            [10] = {0};
char x_Result_B8            [10] = {0};

Fmt(cWrite_All_Data,"%s<%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",Block0,Block1,Block2,Block3,Block4,Block5,Block6,Block7);
and each Block contains the 4 Hex values, e. g.:
Block0 = 3074F701     00 01 04 84
Block1 = CC0D90C0
Block2 = 00000A6A
Block3 = 30303030
Block4 = 00000000
Block5 = 31303030  
Block6 = 00010484 
Block7 = 00010484
// and the CRC function looks like the following:
void Daten_calculate_crc (unsigned char cWrite_All_Data,  const char *ucCRC_MSB,  const char *ucCRC_LSB)
{
    unsigned char ucCRC_H   = {0};
    unsigned char ucCRC_L   = {0};
    const char cDummy [5]   = {0};
    unsigned char x         = 0;
    unsigned int uiCRC = 0x0000;                // Initial value for CRC
    int iNumberofBytes= 64;
    while (iNumberofBytes>0)
    {
        uiCRC ^= ucBuffer[x];                   
        for (int iBit=0;iBit<16;iBit++)
        {
            if (uiCRC&1)
                uiCRC = (uiCRC >> 1) ^ 0xA001;  // Polynomial
            else
                uiCRC>>=1;
        }
        iNumberofBytes--;
        x++;
    }
    ucCRC_H = (uiCRC>>16)&0xFF;                 // CRC in MSB und LSB
    ucCRC_L = uiCRC&0xFF;
    ucCRC_H = ucCRC_H^0xFF;                     // Final Xor- with FF for LSB and MSB  
    ucCRC_L = ucCRC_L^0xFF;
    Fmt(ucCRC_MSB,"%s<%x",ucCRC_L);             // HEX-values
    Fmt(ucCRC_LSB,"%s<%x",ucCRC_H);
    strcpy(cDummy,ucCRC_MSB);
    if (StringLength(ucCRC_MSB) == 1)
    Fmt(ucCRC_MSB, "%s<%s%s","0",cDummy); 
    strcpy(cDummy,ucCRC_LSB);
    if (StringLength(ucCRC_LSB) == 1)
    Fmt(ucCRC_LSB, "%s<%s%s","0",cDummy);
    StringUpperCase (ucCRC_MSB);
    StringUpperCase (ucCRC_LSB);
}
```

I changed the number of bytes from 32 to 64 to match with the Byte numbers that the variable has. But when I double check the CRC result (which are ucCRC_MSB and ucCRC_LSB). with the following website:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
I get other CRC-result numbers. This is the actual problem.
Thanks a lot in advance for the help..
Note: The CRC-16 Type is Maxim. But with another polynomial value in the code (0xA001), but in the website the maxim type is used.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't describe what you have, but show the related code. How does that "variable containing 28 or 32 hex values" look? Is it a string of length 56 or 64? Is it some other array?

Comment: Can you add a small snippet of code that shows what the code currently does, and what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: Also at least for your next question learn how to format a question properly so it is readable. It's easy and it will only take a few minutes to learn the basic stuff.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you i will do that

Comment: @LucaPolito I just added a snipped of the code, thanks a lot for the help :)